# Regex: multiple options for named match

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

I have a regex pattern that is partially catching what I want it to. The pattern can look like any of these

```py
"caller command"
"caller command specifier"
"caller command 'two-worded specifier'"
"caller 'two-worded command' specifier"
"caller 'two-worded command' 'two-worded specifier'"
```

My current code is matching them into named groups and uses the yes/no pattern shown in Python's **re** library documentation.

```
messages = ["your.majesty hello", "proclamation honor Dom", "your.majesty query 'Weekly Coding Challenge'", "your.majesty 'build test' submissions", "your.majesty 'build test' 'Weekly Coding Challenge'"]
call = "(?P<call>.*?)"
command = "(?P<command>'(.*?)'|(.*?))"
specifier = "(?P<specifier>'(.*?.)'|(.*?))"
duo = f"{call}\s{command}"
trio = f"({call}\s{command}\s{specifier})"

regex_duo = re.compile(duo, flags=re.DOTALL)
regex_trio = re.compile(trio)

for msg in messages:
    match = regex_trio.match(msg)
    if match is None:
        match = regex_duo.match(msg)
    print(match)
```

The output of this is

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='your.majesty '>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='proclamation honor '>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 44), match="your.majesty query 'Weekly Coding Challenge'">
<re.Match object; span=(0, 26), match="your.majesty 'build test' ">
<re.Match object; span=(0, 51), match="your.majesty 'build test' 'Weekly Coding Challeng>
```

When I want

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, ...), match='your.majesty hello'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, ...), match='proclamation honor Dom'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, ...), match="your.majesty query 'Weekly Coding Challenge'">
<re.Match object; span=(0, ...), match="your.majesty 'build test' submissions">
<re.Match object; span=(0, ...), match="your.majesty 'build test' 'Weekly Coding Challenge'>
```

1. Is there a better way of doing this rather than what I am currently doing?
2. Why is it cutting off so much even when I use greedy matching?

Comment: Given that every element in your list is a match here, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: csv.reader (reuse the wheel)

Simply transform the problem into a format that is readable by `csv.reader` using `io.StringIO`.

**Code**:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

messages = [
    "your.majesty hello",
    "proclamation honor Dom",
    "your.majesty query 'Weekly Coding Challenge'",
    "your.majesty 'build test' submissions",
    "your.majesty 'build test' 'Weekly Coding Challenge'"
]

# Avoid creating StringIO object multiple times
# for s in messages:
#    reader = csv.reader(StringIO(s), delimiter=" ", quotechar="'")

# load at once
ss = "\n".join(messages)
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(ss), delimiter=" ", quotechar="'")    

for row in reader:  # type(row) is a list
    caller = row[0]
    command = row[1]
    specifier = row[2] if len(row) == 3 else ""
    # check
    print(f"caller = {caller}, command = {command}, specifier = {specifier}")
    # do something with the parsed components here
```

**Output**:

```
caller = your.majesty, command = hello, specifier = 
caller = proclamation, command = honor, specifier = Dom
caller = your.majesty, command = query, specifier = Weekly Coding Challenge
caller = your.majesty, command = build test, specifier = submissions
caller = your.majesty, command = build test, specifier = Weekly Coding Challenge
```

This solution does not produce `re.match` objects, but parses the three components out directly instead. Subsequent operations should be easier as strings than matched groups.

The virtue is like this: We know that existing csv loaders can deal with quotes and space-separated format properly, right? So don't reinvent the wheel, try to reuse it. In this way, the code is also far more maintainable.

### Using pandas.read_csv

Note: One can also use `pandas.read_csv()` to produce a `pandas.Dataframe` directly. The same syntax applies, except that the column names must be assigned manually. The potential missing column (the last column) is properly dealt with.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(StringIO(ss), delimiter=" ", quotechar="'", names=["caller", "command", "specifier"])
Out[38]: 
         caller     command                specifier
0  your.majesty       hello                      NaN
1  proclamation       honor                      Dom
2  your.majesty       query  Weekly Coding Challenge
3  your.majesty  build test              submissions
4  your.majesty  build test  Weekly Coding Challenge
```

## Solution 2: Improved Regex (more general)

For the regex way, yes, it can also be improved a lot. I personally think this is also worth elaboration because many (and possibly the majority) of the parsing tasks cannot be solved by existing libraries.

**Digest**:

- Use [raw-docstring + re.VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) to allow detailed documentation. (The regex is colored quite comfortably in PyCharm.)
- Be more precise about the matching patterns. In general, avoid `.*` unless the matching characters are *really* arbitrary.
- Use the `?` quantifier to indicate optional existence.

**Code**:

```
regex_uni = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<call>\S+) 
    \             # a space character
    (?P<command>  # group 2:
        (?:         # 1st option (non-capturing group):
           '          # begins with SQ
           [^']+      # followed by one or more consecutive non-SQ chars
           '          # ends with SQ
        )
        |         # or
        \S+         # 2nd option: consecutive non-space chars (assuming no SQ)
    )        
    \ ?  # optional space character
    (?P<specifier>       # group 3:   
        (?:'[^']+')|\S+    # same as group 2
    )?                   # but the existence is optional
    """, re.VERBOSE
)

for msg in messages:
    match = regex_uni.match(msg)
    if match is not None:
        print(f"* input = {match.group()}")
        print(f"    call = {match.group('call')}")
        print(f"    command = {match.group('command')}")
        print(f"    specifier = {match.group('specifier')}")
```

**Output**:

```
* input = your.majesty hello
    call = your.majesty
    command = hello
    specifier = None
* input = proclamation honor Dom
    call = proclamation
    command = honor
    specifier = Dom
* input = your.majesty query 'Weekly Coding Challenge'
    call = your.majesty
    command = query
    specifier = 'Weekly Coding Challenge'
* input = your.majesty 'build test' submissions
    call = your.majesty
    command = 'build test'
    specifier = submissions
* input = your.majesty 'build test' 'Weekly Coding Challenge'
    call = your.majesty
    command = 'build test'
    specifier = 'Weekly Coding Challenge'
```